# How to make an array of selected list/menu items

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

Hi I'm new to PHP and I want to know how to make an array of the selected items from multiple select menus. I have an order form that looks like this. The product names have a quantity menu beside it,(assuming there is already a quantity menu until the last product name) I want to get the selected quantities and insert them to 1 field in the database separated by "," just like what you do in checkboxes.
[image]
my PHP so far. I only have the array for the checkboxes(product names). I don't know how to make an array for the quantities/select menus.

```
<?php


   include ("dbinfo.php");

   if (isset($_POST['button']))
    {
       $implode = implode(",",$_POST['CheckboxGroup']);
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_form (orders) VALUES ('".$implode."')") ;
    }
?>

<?php

   if(isset($_POST['button']))
     {
       $implode = implode(",",$_POST['CheckboxGroup']);
       mysql_query("INSERT INTO order_form (name, address, contact_no, payment_option,  claim_option, orders) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['address']."',  '".$_POST['contactno']."', '".$_POST['pay_option']."', '".$_POST['claim_option']."',  '".$implode."')");
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following image.It can solve your problem

[image: array of selected list/menu items]

Comment: what about quantity drop-down box?

Comment: thanks but my problem is i don't know how to get an array from select/drop-down menu, not checkboxes

Comment: means do you want multiple quantities?

Comment: Its only way.use another list for dropdown and maping them.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer to actually have most of that image written out as text? The thing with images with lots of text like this is that they don't index well for search engines so others wouldn't be able to find the information easily.

Comment: @nody yes. after checking the product name, choose a quantity in the drop-down.the checkboxes work fine. i want to get the value of selected drop-downs and insert it to a field,just like in checkboxes. ex. 4,2,6...

Comment: allow multi-select for the drop-down.

Comment: @nody only one quantity per drop-down..the problem is getting an array of those selected quantities to be inserted in a db field

Comment: means one product with one quantity?

Comment: then post quantity with product as you do as normal and save it in DB

Comment: otherwise, you can also create one table with product_id and quantity column.